# Android parsing the package problem

Tags: android

I have completed my one application in android. Then from the ddms I pull the .apk file when i installed it on my android its shows the error "there is a problem parsing the package".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you sign (or re-sign) the .apk

Comment: I am facing with this problem in android studio, in emulator the app it works and the same in the blue stacks but in the phones or tablet the apk says parsing the package problem how can I fix that and what do you mean with sign or resign?

Answer (score 2):

Just for a information those who will read this thread.

Please check the minSdk version in android 
application manifest file and android-platform number in property file 
are same.

I have the same problem that you had but not in emulator .when I
checked it I found that my application minisdk version is different with 
platform number.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Step 1- Go to device Settings(icon) menu

Step 2- Tap on Security

Step 3- Device administration

Step 4- Unknown sources – Check mark Unknown Sources

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to Kariyachan's answer.  Unbeknownst to me, I was packaging my app for Android 4.1 (SDK version 16) when my phone was running 2.3.5 (SDK version 10 !!!).

To avoid the "problem parsing the package" error message:

1. Check your phone's Android version . Settings > About Phone
2. Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels to see what API level matches your phone
3. Adjust the SDK Version # in Eclipse to match the above number
4. Use the wizard to export a signed version (don't worry its easy)
5. Email the apk to your phone and install (or however else you prefer to install)

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

Copy from SD card to somewhere under /data.

```
cp /sdcard/*.apk /data
```

Set ownership and permissions.

```
chown system:system /data/*.apk
chmod 644 /data/*.apk
```